# Flask view with nested if statements raises UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, flask

I'm a beginner to programing, so still trying to learn. I want to return new name of uploaded image. Unfortunately `flask` is not recognising values from nested if statements when i pass them to `render_template` function.

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'image1' referenced before assignment`

So i had to create global values (image1) and it works fine. But i want to ask is there a better way? because it feels very hacky way of doing that.

```py
image1 = None
@app.route("/app_main_page/prekes/ceate",  methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def CreatePrekes():
    global image1
    form = UpdateItemForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.prekes_nuotrauka.data:
            file = save_pict(form.prekes_nuotrauka.data)
            image1 = url_for('static', filename='profile_pictures/' + file)
            post = Preke(pavadinimas=form.pavadinimas.data, apibudinimas=form.apibudinimas.data,
                         prekes_nuotrauka=image1, author=current_user)
            db.session.add(post)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("Your post have been created", "success")
            return redirect(url_for("visos_prekes"))
    return render_template("CreatePrekes.html", title="New Post", form=form)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make an assignment to a variable in a scope, that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly named variable in the outer scope. Since `image1 = url_for('static', filename='profile_pictures/' + file)` assigns a new value to `image1`, the compiler recognizes it as a local variable ignoring any global variables set. Just add `image1 = None` inside your view function.

```
total = 0 # This is a global variable.

def sum(a, b):
    total = a + b # Here total is local variable.
    print(f"Inside the function local total is {total}")
    return total

sum(10, 20)
print(f"Outside the function the global total is {total}")
```

Results

```
"Inside the function local total is 30"
"Outside the function the global total is 0"
```

Comment: I tried it before,. i added image1 = None at the top of the fuction and then set new value in if statment, but when i trying to pass it to render_template it is not recognising new value, and say that image1 cant be None

Comment: @MariusZ you need to set it inside the view function, not outside it.

Comment: The global `image1` variable is ignored once you assign another variable to `image1` inside the view function's.

Comment: @MariusZ A variable is allowed to be None in a render_template function, so your problem must be elsewhere. Is your template itself not allowing image1 to be None? Please add the callback error to your question so we can find the source of your issue.